# Minecraft Groupmanager permissions not working

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server, minecraft-bukkit

I am trying to do away with OP on my server. To achieve this I am trying to use permissions with Group Manager (from essentials).

I have an issue where I am trying to restrict only the ban, op, deop, stop, reload, whitelist and certain group manager commands.

I have deoped myself and removed my username from the config files and added myself to the Admin group but I could still op myself and gain access to the rest of the commands.

Here is my globalgroups.yml file:

```
# These groups only contain permission nodes.
#
# **** You can NOT add anything other than permission nodes ****
# **** This is NOT where you set up the groups which you give to users! ****
# **** goto groupmanager/worlds/worldname/groups.yml if you want to set the actual groups! ****
#
# These collections are to be inherited in your different worlds groups.yml's
# They can also be added as one of a users subgroups, but NOT as a primary group.
# These collections are available to ALL group and user yml's.
#
# Add to and customize these groups to fit your needs.

groups:
  g:default:
    permissions:
    - groupmamager.notify.self
    - multiverse.access.*
    - multiverse.portal.access.*
    - essentials.signs.use.*
    - essentials.help
    - essentials.helpop
    - essentials.list
    - essentials.motd
    - essentials.rules
    - bukkit.command.help
    - essentials.me
    - essentials.jail.allow.help
    - essentials.jail.allow.helpop
    - essentials.jail.allow.rules
    - essentials.tpaccept
    - essentials.tpdeny
    - essentials.worth
    - essentials.balance
    - essentials.afk.auto
    - essentials.sethome.bed

  g:powerusers:
    permissions:
    - groupmanager.notify.self
    - groupmanager.listgroups
    - groupmanager.manwhois
    - groupmanager.notify.other
    - multiverse.portal.access.*
    - multiverse.access.*
    - multiverse.core.confirm
    - multiverse.core.info
    - multiverse.core.list.environments
    - multiverse.core.list.who
    - multiverse.core.list.worlds
    - bukkit.command.plugins
    - bukkit.command.say
    - bukkit.command.tell
    - bukkit.command.whitelist.list
    - essentials.signs.use.*
    - essentials.signs.create.disposal
    - essentials.help
    - essentials.helpop
    - essentials.list
    - essentials.motd
    - essentials.rules
    - bukkit.command.help
    - essentials.mail
    - essentials.mail.send
    - essentials.me
    - essentials.msg
    - essentials.msg.color
    - essentials.msg.format
    - essentials.nick
    - essentials.pay
    - essentials.ping
    - essentials.nick.color
    - essentials.nick.others
    - essentials.realname
    - essentials.top
    - essentials.whois
    - essentials.workbench
    - essentials.tpaccept
    - essentials.tpdeny
    - essentials.tpa
    - treeassist.destroy.*
    - treeassist.replant
    - treeassist.toggle
    - essentials.balance
    - essentials.sell
    - essentials.worth
    - essentials.afk.auto
    - essentials.afk.kickexempt
    - essentials.chat.color
    - essentials.sethome.bed

  g:admin:
    permissions:
    - '*'
    - -essentials.unban
    - -essentials.unbanip
    - -essentials.banip
    - -essentials.tempban
    - -essentials.ban
    - -bukkit.command.reload
    - -bukkit.command.ban.player
    - -bukkit.command.unban.player
    - -bukkit.command.unban.ip
    - -bukkit.command.ban.ip
    - -bukkit.command.op.*
    - -bukkit.command.stop
    - -bukkit.command.save.disable
    - -bukkit.command.whitelist.enable
    - -bukkit.command.whitelist.disable
    - -bukkit.command.whitelist.add
    - -bukkit.command.whitelist.remove
    - -groupmanager.mantogglevalidate
    - -groupmanager.mantogglesave
    - -groupmanager.mangaddv
    - -groupmanager.mangdelv
    - -groupmanager.mangaddp
    - -groupmanager.mangdelp
    - -groupmanager.mangdeli
    - -groupmanager.manuaddv
    - -groupmanager.manudelv
    - -groupmanager.manuaddp
    - -groupmanager.manudelp
    - -groupmanager.manuadd
    - -groupmanager.manudel
    - -groupmanager.manuaddsub
    - -groupmanager.manudelsub
    - -groupmanager.manpromote
    - -groupmanager.mandemote

  g:owner:
    permissions:
    - '*'
```

All of my other permissions (per world) pull from the global groups file so I only need to edit the permissions once.

Comment: Are there any server logs that could signify an error in syntax? Also, do you have access only to the "op" command, or can you use the other negative nodes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried all of the above and more and still didn't get it to work.

Here is the way I was trying to avoid but eventual had to do:
Give each permission manually...

Here is my global groups file which is the file which all of the permissions are read from:

```
# These groups only contain permission nodes.
#
# **** You can NOT add anything other than permission nodes ****
# **** This is NOT where you set up the groups which you give to users! ****
# **** goto groupmanager/worlds/worldname/groups.yml if you want to set the actual groups! ****
#
# These collections are to be inherited in your different worlds groups.yml's
# They can also be added as one of a users subgroups, but NOT as a primary group.
# These collections are available to ALL group and user yml's.
#
# Add to and customize these groups to fit your needs.

groups:
  g:default:
    permissions:
    - groupmamager.notify.self
    - multiverse.access.*
    - multiverse.portal.access.*
    - essentials.signs.use.*
    - essentials.help
    - essentials.helpop
    - essentials.list
    - essentials.motd
    - essentials.rules
    - bukkit.command.help
    - essentials.me
    - essentials.jail.allow.help
    - essentials.jail.allow.helpop
    - essentials.jail.allow.rules
    - essentials.tpaccept
    - essentials.tpdeny
    - essentials.worth
    - essentials.balance
    - essentials.afk.auto
    - essentials.sethome.bed
    - bukkit.command.ban.list
    - essentials.recipe
    - essentials.ban.notify


  g:powerusers:
    permissions:
    - essentials.recipe
    - groupmanager.notify.self
    - groupmanager.listgroups
    - groupmanager.manwhois
    - groupmanager.notify.other
    - multiverse.portal.access.*
    - multiverse.access.*
    - multiverse.core.confirm
    - multiverse.core.info
    - multiverse.core.list.environments
    - multiverse.core.list.who
    - multiverse.core.list.worlds
    - bukkit.command.plugins
    - bukkit.command.say
    - bukkit.command.tell
    - bukkit.command.whitelist.list
    - essentials.signs.use.*
    - essentials.signs.create.disposal
    - essentials.help
    - essentials.helpop
    - essentials.list
    - essentials.motd
    - essentials.rules
    - bukkit.command.help
    - essentials.mail
    - essentials.mail.send
    - essentials.me
    - essentials.msg
    - essentials.msg.color
    - essentials.msg.format
    - essentials.nick
    - essentials.pay
    - essentials.ping
    - essentials.nick.color
    - essentials.nick.others
    - essentials.realname
    - essentials.top
    - essentials.whois
    - essentials.workbench
    - essentials.tpaccept
    - essentials.tpdeny
    - essentials.tpa
    - treeassist.destroy.*
    - treeassist.replant
    - treeassist.toggle
    - essentials.balance
    - essentials.sell
    - essentials.worth
    - essentials.afk.auto
    - essentials.afk.kickexempt
    - essentials.chat.color
    - essentials.sethome.bed
    - bukkit.command.ban.list
    - essentials.ban.notify

  g:admin:
    permissions:
    - bukkit.command.version
    - bukkit.command.plugins
    - bukkit.command.timings
    - bukkit.command.tell
    - bukkit.command.kill
    - bukkit.command.me
    - bukkit.command.help
    - bukkit.command.kick
    - bukkit.command.ban.list
    - bukkit.command.teleport
    - bukkit.command.give
    - bukkit.command.save.perform
    - bukkit.command.list
    - bukkit.command.say
    - bukkit.command.whitelist.list
    - bukkit.command.time.*
    - bukkit.command.gamemode
    - bukkit.command.xp
    - bukkit.command.toggledownfall
    - bukkit.command.defaultgamemode
    - bukkit.command.seed
    - bukkit.command.enchant
    - bukkit.command.weather.*
    - bukkit.command.clear
    - bukkit.command.difficulty
    - bukkit.command.spawnpoint
    - bukkit.command.gamerule
    - bukkit.command.effect
    - bukkit.command.setidletimeout
    - bukkit.command.setworldspawn
    - bukkit.command.achievement
    - bukkit.broadcast
    - essentials.itemspawn.*
    - essentials.worth
    - essentials.worlds.*
    - essentials.world
    - essentials.workbench
    - essentials.whois
    - essentials.weather
    - essentials.warps.*
    - essentials.warp.*
    - essentials.warp
    - essentials.vanish.*
    - essentials.vanish
    - essentials.unlimited.*
    - essentials.unlimited
    - essentials.tree
    - essentials.tptoggle.*
    - essentials.tptoggle
    - essentials.tppos
    - essentials.tpohere
    - essentials.tpo
    - essentials.tphere
    - essentials.tpdeny
    - essentials.tpall
    - essentials.tpahere
    - essentials.tpaccept
    - essentials.tpaall
    - essentials.tpa
    - essentials.tp.*
    - essentials.tp
    - essentials.top
    - essentials.togglejail.*
    - essentials.togglejail
    - essentials.time.*
    - essentials.time
    - essentials.thunder
    - essentials.teleport.*
    - essentials.suicide
    - essentials.sudo
    - essentials.sudo.exempt
    - essentials.speed.*
    - essentials.speed
    - essentials.spawnmob.*
    - essentials.spawnmob
    - essentials.spawner.*
    - essentials.spawn.*
    - essentials.spawn
    - essentials.socialspy.*
    - essentials.socialspy
    - essentials.sleepingignored
    - essentials.signs.*
    - essentials.setworth
    - essentials.setwarp
    - essentials.setspawn
    - essentials.setjail
    - essentials.sethome.*
    - essentials.sethome
    - essentials.sell
    - essentials.seen.*
    - essentials.seen
    - essentials.rules
    - essentials.repair.*
    - essentials.repair
    - essentials.remove
    - essentials.recipe
    - essentials.realname
    - essentials.ptime.*
    - essentials.ptime
    - essentials.protect.*
    - essentials.protect
    - essentials.powertooltoggle
    - essentials.powertool.*
    - essentials.powertool
    - essentials.ping
    - essentials.pay
    - essentials.oversizedstacks
    - essentials.nick.*
    - essentials.nick
    - essentials.near
    - essentials.mute.*
    - essentials.mute
    - essentials.msg.*
    - essentials.msg
    - essentials.motd
    - essentials.more
    - essentials.me
    - essentials.mail.*
    - essentials.mail
    - essentials.list.*
    - essentials.list
    - essentials.lightning.*
    - essentials.lightning
    - essentials.kits.*
    - essentials.kits
    - essentials.killall
    - essentials.kill.force
    - essentials.kill
    - essentials.kick.notify
    - essentials.kick
    - essentials.jump
    - essentials.joinfullserver
    - essentials.jails
    - essentials.itemspawn.*
    - essentials.itemdb
    - essentials.item
    - essentials.invsee.*
    - essentials.invsee
    - essentials.info
    - essentials.ignore
    - essentials.home.*
    - essentials.home
    - essentials.helpop.*
    - essentials.helpop
    - essentials.help.*
    - essentials.help
    - essentials.heal.*
    - essentials.heal
    - essentials.hat
    - essentials.god.*
    - essentials.god
    - essentials.give
    - essentials.getpos.*
    - essentials.getpos
    - essentials.geoip.*
    - essentials.gc
    - essentials.gamemode.*
    - essentials.gamemode
    - essentials.fly.*
    - essentials.fly
    - essentials.firework.*
    - essentials.firework
    - essentials.fireball
    - essentials.feed.*
    - essentials.feed
    - essentials.ext
    - essentials.exp.*
    - essentials.exp
    - essentials.essentials
    - essentials.enderchest.*
    - essentials.enderchest
    - essentials.enchantments.*
    - essentials.enchant
    - essentials.eco.*
    - essentials.eco
    - essentials.depth
    - essentials.delwarp
    - essentials.deljail
    - essentials.delhome.*
    - essentials.delhome
    - essentials.customtext
    - essentials.compass
    - essentials.clearinventory.*
    - essentials.clearinventory
    - essentials.chat.*
    - essentials.burn
    - essentials.build.*
    - essentials.build
    - essentials.broadcast
    - essentials.break.*
    - essentials.break
    - essentials.book.*
    - essentials.book
    - essentials.bigtree
    - essentials.ban.notify
    - essentials.balancetop
    - essentials.balance.*
    - essentials.balance
    - essentials.backup
    - essentials.back.*
    - essentials.back
    - essentials.afk.*
    - essentials.afk
    - essentials.itemspawn.*
    - alldayallnight.admin
    - worldedit.*
    - treeassist.*
    - multiverse.*
    - prism.*
    - lagg.*
    - groupmanager.manwhois
    - groupmanager.manulistp
    - groupmanager.manulistv
    - groupmanager.listgroups
    - groupmanager.manglistp
    - groupmanager.manglistv
    - groupmanager.mancheckw
    - groupmanager.notify.*
```

Answer (score 1):

From looking at the [wiki](http://ess.khhq.net/wiki/Group_Manager#Permissions_nodes), your problem lies in the `'*'` in the first line of your Admin group.

> You can also give the * permission on itself, without giving a plugin, this would cause the group to have access to every command in every plugin.

You're still giving yourself all permissions as an admin, with the use of the '*' character.

Comment: So what I understand from you post is that the wildcard is overriding the negative nodes? If so then can you give me an example for what I should do?

Comment: That's odd... Last night, I even copied your nodes over so I could look more easily in a larger font... I'm looking at my copy right now and it doesn't have the negative nodes. My answer seems to be completely incorrect. Sorry!

Comment: So my permissions were right?

Comment: Probably. I'll go through it again when I get home. My internet went out last night, so I couldn't do more research. But don't you worry, we'll get ya figured out. If not me, some other Arqadian will. =)

Comment: Any updates on if it works?

Comment: From what I'm finding, it should be working. But I want you to try something for me, just on a theory. Try giving the owner group the negative node for oping. I know you said you removed yourself from the configs, and by that I'm assuming that you mean it shouldn't see you as owner, but it's an idea.

Comment: It didn't work. I also tried putting the negative permissions on the top of the wild card...

Comment: It was worth a shot... I'll keep looking. You're not missing any permissions you, by chance? Nothing like that?

Comment: perhaps replace the `.op.*` with `.op.player`? Meanwhile I'll keep looking.

Comment: i'll try that...

Comment: It did not work :(

Comment: Any news? (required extra characters)

Comment: Try breaking the op permission up, as in on the example page:https://github.com/essentials/Essentials/blob/release/EssentialsGroupManager/src/globalgroups.yml

Answer (score 0):

Use `-essentials.*` Instead of `- -essentials.*`. If it still doesnt work make sure you use 4 SPACE not TAB before the `-`

Comment: I have never used the TAB key because YAML is not compatible with the TAB key. Thanks for your help but I had to do it the manual way.

Answer (score 0):

Connect the `-` with `essentials` and all other permissions. Ex: `-essentials.kits.PvP`